# Stop printing amount of the element in foreach loop powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

The foreach loop just keeps print out the amount of element in it as the following code. I want to stop it from printing it out.

```
$ADSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ADSearch.SearchRoot ="LDAP://$Domain"
$ADSearch.SearchScope = "subtree"
$ADSearch.PageSize = 100
$ADSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=$objectClass)"

$properies =@("distinguishedName",
"sAMAccountName",
"mail",
"lastLogonTimeStamp",
"pwdLastSet",
"accountExpires",
"userAccountControl")

foreach($pro in $properies)
{
    $ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)   
}
```

At the moment it gives:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: It is telling there are 7 elements added into the list whose index starts from 0. You can always pipe that to `out-null` or redirect it to $null like `>> $null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
foreach($pro in $properies)
{
    $ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)   
}
```

To:

```
foreach($pro in $properies)
{
    $ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)| out-null
}
```

Comment: @Ender: My pleasure. Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable

Comment: sure I will :D after 10 mins

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to `[void]` the "offending" line:

```
foreach($pro in $properies)
{
    [void]$ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)
}
```

Comment: I liked it. Its the best and old school method. Always declare them as VOID :)